# React @reach/Router issues How to make the switchcase work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make my App.js route to my People.jsx etc.. but it is not working correctly. I hope I could fix the issue from there if I could make this work. I have been trying to do this for about 2 hours with the 20 min rule but this one I need help with. I have tried other variations but my goal is to get the,`theID` over to Person as well. I am thinking about using `{useContext }` to do that but I can't even get it to route. I wish I knew what I was doing wrong so I could correct it but other people are using different types of routers and I was confused with them even more.

I updated it with links still a no go for me any other suggestions?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import People from './components/People'
import Planet from './components/Planets'
import Starship from './components/Starships'
import { Router, Link } from '@reach/router';

function App() {
  const [starwarsState, setStarwarsState] = useState('')
  const [theID, setTheID] = useState('')

  const selectedState = (e) => {
    setStarwarsState(e.target.value)
  }

  const switchItem = () => {
    switch (starwarsState) {
      case 'people':
        <Link path='/people/' />;
        break;
      case 'planets':
        <Link path="/planets/" />;
        break;
      case 'starships':
        <Link path='/starships/' />;
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  const addId = e => {
    setTheID(e.target.value)
    console.log(theID)
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header' >
        Search For: &nbsp;
        <select onChange={selectedState} className='form-control-lg bg-dark text-white'>
          <option value='people' active >People</option>
          <option value='planets' >Planets</option>
          <option value='starships' >Starships</option>
        </select>

           &nbsp; ID: &nbsp;
           <input type='text' onChange={addId} className='form-control-lg col-sm-1 bg-dark text-white' />&nbsp;
           <button className='btn-lg btn-warning' onClick={switchItem}  >Search Item</button>
        <Router>
          <People path='/people/' />
          <Planet path="/planets/" />
          <Starship path='/starships/' />
        </Router>
      </header>
      {starwarsState}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

People.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import { Link } from '@reach/router';

const People = props => {

    const [peopleData, setpeopleData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${props.theID}`)
            .then(response => { setpeopleData(response.data) })

        console.log(peopleData)
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <span> the People have spoken</span> 
            <Link to='/people' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default People;
```

Comment: Also could you be descriptive when you do correct me so I can learn.

Comment: Any JSX you want rendered needs to be rendered by the functional component return, or returned by a function ***in*** the JSX. You can't simply return JSX from a click callback and expect it to be rendered. Why are you trying to conditionally render 3 different routers? Just unconditionally render one router with all three routes and conditionally navigate to the route path rendering the component you want rendered. It is at this point you can then pass additional data to the routes.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean? I really a little confused by what you mean by that

Comment: Also I want it to pass the information I set as well so when I click the button it goes to the page. This how I came up with it in my  head so that is why I am trying to render depending on what is click. I am trying to see a better way of doing this.

Comment: Can you show me an example?  Like that makes no sense to me except that I should do something like `switch(example) People <Link path='/people/'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

You aren't actually rendering the routes/links from `switchItem` since `onClick` callbacks can't return renderable UI directly to the render method.

## Solution

Unconditionally render your routes all at the same time within a single `Router` and imperatively navigate to them in the `switchItem` handler.

App

```
...
import { Router, navigate } from "@reach/router";
...

function App() {
  const [starwarsState, setStarwarsState] = useState("");
  const [theID, setTheID] = useState("");

  ...

  const switchItem = () => {
    switch (starwarsState) {
      case "people":
        navigate("/people"); // <-- imperative navigation
        break;
      case "planets":
        navigate("/planets");
        break;
      case "starships":
        navigate("/starships");
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Search For: &nbsp;
        <select
          onChange={selectedState}
          value={starwarsState}
          className="form-control-lg bg-dark text-white"
        >
          <option disabled value="">
            Choose Path
          </option>
          <option value="people">
            People
          </option>
          <option value="planets">Planets</option>
          <option value="starships">Starships</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp; ID: &nbsp;
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={addId}
          className="form-control-lg col-sm-1 bg-dark text-white"
        />
        &nbsp;
        <button className="btn-lg btn-warning" onClick={switchItem}>
          Search Item
        </button>
      </header>
      <Router>
        <People path="/people" theID={theID} /> // <-- pass `theID` state as prop
        <Planet path="/planets" />
        <Starship path='/starships' />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

People

```
const People = ({ theID }) => {
  const [peopleData, setpeopleData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${theID}`)
      .then(response => { setpeopleData(response.data) });
  }, [theID]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>The ID: {theID}</div>
      <span>the People have spoken</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-reach-router-issues-how-to-make-the-switchcase-work]

Comment: This is great but the only problem I have with it is when I use it is, if I already used it in the People.jsx and try to change the person it don't I have to click on planets then back to people if I am already in that route.

Comment: @ALTHEPAL78 I don't understand what you mean by any of this. What is already used in `People.jsx`? What person is changing? Are you referring to the `theID` state in `App` that is passed to the `People` component?

Comment: I click in people and type 1,  I get that informations but if I try and put 2 in the ID field and click search it won't let me do it again. The state changes but it won't run or pull a new request to the API

Comment: @ALTHEPAL78 Ah, I see. This is because the effect has an empty dependency array and only runs once when mounted. You can simply add `theID` to the dependency array if you want the effect to trigger again when `theID` is updated in the parent. I updated code in answer and in the linked codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Imperative Routing (not switch statement) with Event Handlers

Your code is using a switch statement in combination with the switchItem() function. This is not how to redirect the user imperatively (meaning, through something other than a link clicked directly by the user).

To imperatively route your users, use the `navigate` method.

Via Reach Router docs ([link](https://reach.tech/router/tutorial/09-navigate)):

> Sometimes you need to navigate in response to something other than the user clicking on a link. For this we have navigate. Let’s import navigate.

```
import {
  Router,
  Link,
  navigate
} from "@reach/router"
```

In your case, the entire switch statement can be rewritten as follows:

```
useEffect(() => navigate(`/${starwarsState}`), [starwarsState])
```

useEffect will watch for changes to the starwarsState, which is either going to be 'people', 'planets', or 'starships'. Once a change occurs, it will navigate the user to the corresponding path.

## Solution: Routing Only

*The following solution doesn't implement axios, it focuses solely on the client-side routing logic.*

I found some other issues with your code when I was working through a solution. Here is a version that I wrote that implements parameter-level routing while also making some other cleanup (refactoring the swapi categories into a config object, etc).

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useWhatChanged } from "@simbathesailor/use-what-changed";
import { Router, Link, navigate } from "@reach/router";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { People, Person } from './components/People'
import { Planets, Planet } from './components/Planets'
import { Starships, Starship } from './components/Starships'
import './App.css';

function App() {

  // destructure categories from config
  const { people, planets, starships } = config.categories

  // initialize state
  const [starwarsState, setStarwarsState] = useState(people);
  const [theID, setTheID] = useState('');

  // log updates to ID and starwarsState 
  useWhatChanged([starwarsState, theID], 'starwarsState, theID')

  // change state on input from user
  const addId = e => setTheID(e.target.value)
  const selectCategory = (e) => setStarwarsState(e.target.value)

  // route the user based on starwarsState
  useEffect(() => navigate(`/${starwarsState}`), [starwarsState])

  // search swapi based on category and id
  const searchSwapi = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate(`/${starwarsState}/${theID}`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className='App-header' >

        Search For:
        <form onSubmit={searchSwapi}>
          <select onChange={selectCategory} className='form-control-lg bg-dark text-white'>
            <option value={people} >People</option>
            <option value={planets} >Planets</option>
            <option value={starships} >Starships</option>
          </select>
          ID:
        <input type='text' onChange={addId} className='form-control-lg col-sm-1 bg-dark text-white' />
          <button className='btn-lg btn-warning' >Search Item</button>
        </form>
      </header>

      <Router>
        <People path='/people/'>
          <Person path=':personId' />
        </People>
        <Planets path="/planets/">
          <Planet path=':planetId' />
        </Planets>
        <Starships path='/starships/'>
          <Starship path=':starshipId' />
        </Starships>
      </Router>

    </div>
  )
}

const config = {
  categories: {
    people: 'people',
    planets: 'planets',
    starships: 'starships'
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Planets.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const Planets = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      <span> the Planets have spoken</span>
      {props.children}

    </div>
  )
}


export const Planet = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      Planet Data
    </div>
  )
}
```

**People.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const People = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> the People have spoken</span>

      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export const Person = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      Person Data
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Starships.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const Starships = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      <span> the Starships have spoken</span>

      {props.children}

    </div>
  )
}

export const Starship = props => {

  return (
    <div>
      Starship Data
    </div>
  )
}
```

## [UPDATE] Solution: Routing with API Calls

The following solution takes the code from above and refactors it using the [state management pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzlurzsCW4M&t=917s) proposed by [Leigh Halliday](https://github.com/leighhalliday). The solution adds three things:

- [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for managing global state
- [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for memoizing AppContent component
- [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) for managing remote API calls to SWAPI.

[View code on GitHub](https://github.com/geochronology/reach-router-switchcase)

**App.js**

```
// App.js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  memo
} from 'react'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query-devtools";
import { useWhatChanged } from "@simbathesailor/use-what-changed";
import { Router, navigate } from "@reach/router";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { People, Person } from './components/People'
import { Planets, Planet } from './components/Planets'
import { Starships, Starship } from './components/Starships'
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';


// APP w/ CONTEXT PROVIDER
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StarwarsProvider>
        <AppContent />
      </StarwarsProvider>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </>

  )
}

// CREATE CONTEXT
export const StarwarsContext = createContext()

// CONTEXT PROVIDER
function StarwarsProvider({ children }) {

  // import categories
  const categories = config.categories

  // destructure default category of search selection
  const { people } = categories

  // initialize state
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(people);
  const [theID, setTheID] = useState('');


  return (
    <StarwarsContext.Provider value={{
      category,
      setCategory,
      theID,
      setTheID,
      categories,
      fetchStarwarsData
    }}>
      <AppContent />
    </StarwarsContext.Provider>
  )
}

async function fetchStarwarsData(category, id) {
  if (!id) {
    return
  }

  const response = await Axios.get(
    `https://swapi.dev/api/${category}/${id}`
  ).then(res => res.data)
  // const data = await response.json()
  const data = response
  // console.log(data)
  return data
}


// APP CONTENT
const AppContent = memo(() => {

  // import global state into component
  const { category, setCategory } = useContext(StarwarsContext)
  const { theID, setTheID } = useContext(StarwarsContext)

  // destructure categories
  const { categories: { people, planets, starships } } = useContext(StarwarsContext)

  // log updates to ID and category 
  useWhatChanged([category, theID], 'category, theID')

  // change state on input from user
  const addId = e => setTheID(e.target.value)
  const selectCategory = (e) => setCategory(e.target.value)

  // route the user based on category
  useEffect(() => navigate(`/${category}`), [category])

  // search swapi based on category and id
  const searchSwapi = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate(`/${category}/${theID}`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className='App-header' >

        Search For:
        <form onSubmit={searchSwapi}>
          <select onChange={selectCategory} className='form-control-lg bg-dark text-white'>
            <option value={people} >People</option>
            <option value={planets} >Planets</option>
            <option value={starships} >Starships</option>
          </select>
          ID:
        <input type='text' onChange={addId} className='form-control-lg col-sm-1 bg-dark text-white' />
          <button className='btn-lg btn-warning' >Search Item</button>
        </form>
      </header>

      <Router>
        <People path='/people/'>
          <Person path=':personId' fetchStarwarsData />
        </People>
        <Planets path="/planets/">
          <Planet path=':planetId' fetchStarwarsData />
        </Planets>
        <Starships path='/starships/'>
          <Starship path=':starshipId' fetchStarwarsData />
        </Starships>
      </Router>

    </div>
  )
})

const config = {
  categories: {
    people: 'people',
    planets: 'planets',
    starships: 'starships'
  }
}
```

**People.js**

```
// People.js
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { StarwarsContext, StarwarsProvider } from "../App"

export const People = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> the People have spoken</span>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export const Person = () => {

  const { category, theID, fetchStarwarsData } = React.useContext(StarwarsContext)

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery([category, theID], fetchStarwarsData)

  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>oop!! error ocurred</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>/{category}/{theID}</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>

    </div>
  )
}
```

**Planets.js**

```
// Planets.js
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { StarwarsContext, StarwarsProvider } from "../App"

export const Planets = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> the Planets have spoken</span>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}


export const Planet = props => {

  const { category, theID, fetchStarwarsData } = React.useContext(StarwarsContext)

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery([category, theID], fetchStarwarsData)

  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>oop!! error ocurred</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>/{category}/{theID}</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>

    </div>
  )
}
```

**Starships.js**

```
// Starships.js
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { StarwarsContext, StarwarsProvider } from "../App"

export const Starships = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> the Starships have spoken</span>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export const Starship = () => {

  const { category, theID, fetchStarwarsData } = React.useContext(StarwarsContext)

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery([category, theID], fetchStarwarsData)

  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>oop!! error ocurred</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>/{category}/{theID}</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but then how do I pull from the api site that is no longer in this version

Comment: I was working on that last night as well but was running into some issues so I decided just to focus on the switching logic first. I'll take a look at the code again later to think about how to implement the API calls using this architecture.

Comment: @ALTHEPAL78 First, watch this video on state management: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzlurzsCW4M&t=917s). I took the same pattern and used it to get my solution working with SWAPI. The full solution is posted here and on GitHub ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzlurzsCW4M&t=917s)). If this solution works for you too then please consider marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: That looks awesome but now I need a class in all the different @ things you are using. I am trying to take baby steps to it. This is confusing to me because I only seen but not have used, many of those imports you are importing so I am trying to get the basics down first.

Comment: @ALTHEPAL78 That's really great feedback and I totally get where you're coming from. Let me see if I can break down the same code using fewer third party libraries so that it's easier to comprehend.

Comment: Christian Perry Thank you very much :)